# Compass & Hibernate: prevent inflation of proxy objects during indexing

Tags: hibernate, proxy, lucene, indexing, compass-lucene

I am trying to prevent my compass (2.2) indexing from inflating lazy hibernate references.

I know there is a setting for this

```
compass.marshalling.hibernate.initializeProxy
```

But after a lot of debugging the compass sources I found out, that this setting is not even passed to `HibernateProxyExtractor`.

I am applying the setting in my XML config as follows, is this correct?

```
<bean id="compass" class="org.compass.spring.LocalCompassBean">
    <!-- .... -->
    <property name="compassSettings">
        <prop key="compass.marshalling.hibernate.initializeProxy">false</prop>
        <!-- ... -->
    </property>
</bean>
```

While debugging, I found out that `DefaultConverterLookup` creates and configures `ClassMappingConverter` (which in turn configures `ProyExtractorHelper` which in turn configures `HibernateProxyExtractor`). However, configuration settings are only passed to `ClassMappingConverter`, if they are prefixed with "`compass.converter`" (`CompassEnvironment.Converter.PREFIX`), which is not the case for `compass.marshalling.hibernate.initializeProxy`

Note: I am not at all a Compass/Lucene expert, so maybe I just do not get how to configure this correctly.